# Deleting a cookie from a different domain when running locally

Tags: javascript, cookies, setcookie

Per cookie specification this is not allowed (same principle as Same Origin Policy for ajax calls). As far as SOP is concerned, it does not apply, when you are running your javascript from file:/// (for example inside of a UIWebView). This is well documented and working in my example too. What about cookies though?

I have an app that makes a request to a server via javascript running, for all intends and purposes, locally (file:///). The authentication request sets a cookie with name let's say 'alpha', path: '/' and domain 'serverdomain.com'. During  logout I need to clear the aforementioned cookie but I get the feeling that my attempts fail because I don't have access to it because it is considered to be from a different domain. Does that sound familiar? Or am I way off here? Is there a way to accomplish such a feat?

EXAMPLE

I am running my javascript on Chrome (using file:/// as the URI). I initiate a login and soon enough I can see the following cookie in the cookie manager plugin (this is not the actual cookie but it looks the same except for the name which we can say it is 'alpha'). The cookie is not marked http only but it has the 'session' and 'secure' checkboxes checked (unlike the screenshot below).

[image: screenshot from cookie manager]

Now keep in mind that if I use the 'inspect element' feature of Chrome and go to 'Cookies', I get a 'There are no cookies for this site'.

[image: chrome - inspect element/cookies]

During logoff I need to delete that cookie. So I do this in javascript:

```
document.cookie="alpha=; expires=Thu, 10 May 2000 15:07:07 GMT"
```

The cookie does not go away. The only way I can make it go away is by deleting it from the cookie manager. Should I be able to delete this cookie (while running from file:///)? If so how?

Answer (score 2):

If the cookie was created on a different domain, this cookie won't be sent by the client to the server on the second domain, so you cannot remove it. You can set a cookie with the same name on this domain but that won't be the same cookie as the one that exists on the first domain.

Comment: Not sure this answers my question. The cookie is set by the server and returned to the client. Every subsequent request i make to that server contains that same cookie. The question becomes, how can i delete the cookie so on the nest request to the serve rthe cookie does not get sent. Since i appear to be running from a different domain is that possible?

Comment: @fnCzar, if you are running on a different domain the client will not send the cookie at all. But if you are saying that the client is sending the cookie this means that this cookie was created on this domain and you can delete it from the server by setting its expires header to a date in the past.

Comment: But the question is can i remove from the client?

Comment: Yes, if it is not a session cookie (i.e. generated with the HttpOnly flag from the server) and if you have access to it.

Comment: Darin, thanks for all your help. There is something that I am probably not explaining right because for the life of me, I can not delete that cookie. Can you take a look at a more elaborate example below and comment? Thanks!

Comment: What's the domain property of the cookie?

Comment: It is ".domainname.com". Thanks for your continued effort.